# watchkit extension 2 iOS app crash at start in simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, watchkit, watchos-2

I have configured the WatchKit App to run in my project (WatchOS2).
When I try to run it into the simulator the WatchKit App start perfectly, but each times I'm trying to start the iOS app, this one crash.

The simulator's log show me that :

com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.5F243C10-E98D-4A20-8950-2742FE6CABD5.launchd_sim[13288] (UIKitApplication:com.MyCompany.MyProject[0x847][13496]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5

All of my code in the application delegate is in comment. just enough to start

If I build and use my main app target with the same simulator setting, that works nicely. it just when I build and run the watchkit extension target.

I tried to clean everything (derived data, simulator setting and contents).

I know, it is not the simulator, because with a new project, the issue is not here. it might be something set somewhere ??

but nothing works, any idea ?.

Answer (score 2):

Your application aborted, likely due to a failed assertion.  You should look at the crash log (in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports) for more details.